# Constraints messing me up

Tags: objective-c, xcode, constraints, ios6

I have 5 buttons, aligned in the right side of the view. I have a method, that takes the frame of the sender (the button), creates a UIImageView with that frame, removes sender from superview and add the imageView at that location, and it works EXCEPT that those constraints mess me up.

It seems like when i remove one of the buttons, it changes the size of all the others, and i cant explain why.

I would love to simply just remove the auto-layout feature, but i would like to make the app for both iPhone 5 and iPhone 4 screen sizes.

So what do i do here?

IN SHORT:
I have 5 buttons on a view, a method creates a UIImageView with the sender buttons frame, remove button and add img view at that location. Works, but after changing 1 button the size of all the other buttons change. How to prevent this? i think it is because they are aligned to each other in "pairs".

Thanks

// EDIT
Images of my setup and the constraints, not sure which one is giving me problems but maybe the bottom one, since it is linked to the other buttons. i DONT want my buttons to change size if i programmatically remove one of them, and that is whats happening.
[image: Setup]

[image: Constraints]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Remove the Auto - layout like this.

[image]

Then use the Bounds property for getting heights for different iPhones and then set the frames in respective way.

You can get the height by checking

```
 if([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568)
 {
         //newer iphone
 }
 else
 {
         //older iphones
 }
```

NEW EDIT :

So what you actually need is to remove the PADDING between the First Button and SEcond Button.

You have to remove it and then align every View with respect to Y-Axis from top.
This would do the job.

Comment: Yeah that would work, but i would think there was another way of getting the auto-constraints feature to work for you, since it gives you some nice features, it just seems there is this small size-matching thing that is bugging me. I've tried to remove the constraint manually but it add's it again itself. Or maybe what you posted is just the way to go?

Comment: You have asked that you wanted to remove the Auto-layout feature, so I showed how to do it. Anyways, I think if you are giving support for iOS Versions less than 6 then you shouldn't use Auto-Layout. However, if you do not require older iOS Support then Auto-Layout is the way to go.

Comment: Post some images for constraints in which you are facing difficulties in...also, You could get more constraints knowledge from here. http://www.raywenderlich.com/20881/beginning-auto-layout-part-1-of-2

Comment: I added some screenshots above of my setup and constraints on those buttons. Thanks for helping me out, really appriciate it. The buttons change size if i remove one of them programatically, and i dont want that to happen.

Comment: that sounds more like it, can you explain how i would go about doing this, not quite sure i understand? thanks again for helping me! How do i do it?

Comment: I mean, i don't know what you want me to do. How do i remove the padding? The constraint i have issues with is the "align leading to" i THINK, but still not sure how you want me to fix it?